# Cannot connect to MongoDB errno:61

Tags: macos, mongodb, osx-mavericks

I installed MongoDB using macports and tried running the `mongo` command in order to start the mongo shell. I received the following errors:

```
warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused

Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed 
at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
```

I then ran `mongod` and received the following error:

```
$ [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=11984 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Nikitas-MacBook-Air.local
$ [initandlisten] 
$ [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
$ [initandlisten] db version v2.6.0
$ [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
$ [initandlisten] build info: Darwin tennine-slave.macports.org 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 
13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_55
$ [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
$ [initandlisten] options: {}
$ [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating
$ [initandlisten] dbexit: 
$ [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
$ [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
$ [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
$ [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
$ [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
$ [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
$ [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
$ [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
$ [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Where do I create the `/data/db` directory, at root? Would the second error be the reason for the `errno:61` when I run `mongo`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you would create `/data/db` at root. The [MongoDB Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) suggests the following command for creation on OS X `mkdir -p /data/db`.

Regarding your second question, also yes. Since the Mongo Daemon failed to start and isn't listening you get the connection error.

MongoDB defaults to `/data/db` for the data directory. You can override the default using the `--dbpath` option on the `mongod` command (also on the doc link above).

Comment: This worked, thanks. I created the directory and used 'sudo mongod' to open a connection. After I used 'mongo' and it finally opened the connection to the shell.

Comment: Perhaps the `mongod` user should own the directory?

Answer (score 23):

I encountered similar problem. I have detailed the error trace and solution [on this blog](http://www.alirazabhayani.com/2015/02/mongodb-correct-way-to-start-error-Cannot-connect-to-mongodb-errno-61-connection-refused.html) This is step by step process I did to solve this issue:

Step 1 - Installation ( Don't follow this step if you have already installed MongoDB ):

```
brew update
brew install mongodb
```

Step 2 - Run Mongo Daemon:

```
mkdir -p /data/db
sudo mongod
```

Step 3 - Run Mongo Shell Interface:

```
mongo
```

In this sequence, I was able to run the mongo command without any error.

Comment: I have question that should i always keep a terminal window for mongod process?

Comment: If you want it to start automatically on startup, you may use this simple utility on [mongodb site](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/28925264384/macosx-preferences-pane-for-mongodb) . It has this option to start the server automatically on startup.

Answer (score 3):

```
** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
```

you can add one line into your /etc/bashrc, the warning will disappear.

```
ulimit -S -n 1024
```

use `chown -R {user} /data/db` to change the owner of `/data/db` from root to yourself.
Then you can start mongo shell just by `mongo`, no need to use `sudo mongo`.