# Can not connect to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack, mean, database

OMG here is my error message:

> 2015-07-06T16:06:10.773-0400 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
>   2015-07-06T16:06:10.775-0400 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
>       at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
>       at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
>   exception: connect failed

I literally have no idea where to start. I tried looking for the MongoDB logs without success. What should I do?

Comment: mac osx is what i'm using

Comment: this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439343/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-errno61

Comment: yet I tried multiple command:

       454  brew services list
  455  brew services stop mongodb
  456  brew services start mongodb
  457  mongo
  458  mongo
  459  mongo
  460  brew services list
  461  mongo
  462  brew services restart mongodb
  463  mongo
  464  ps -ef | grep mongo
  465  mongo
  466  mongo
  467  mongo
  468  mongo
  469  brew services stop mongodb
  470  mongod
  471  ps -ef | grep mongo
  472  sudo kill 26392
  473  ps -ef | grep mongo
  474  brew services start mongodb
  475  mongo
  476  mongod status
  477  mongo
  478  brew services lsit

Comment: is mongod running and did you create a database folder

Comment: Has it worked before?

Comment: @PeterWard run `mongod`. This should be it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439343/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-errno61

Comment: i was about to do a presentation -- it worked until my boss came and tried to fix my authentication!!!

Comment: i even ran mongo during the presentation

Comment: something weird is going on!